# Google maps Infowindow ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

very new to react. I'm using google-maps-react-api. I have two files. Index.js and MapMarker.js. It loads a few location points with info windows already loaded. I can close the window but when clicking on the marker they do not reopen. My onCLick events do not work as I expect. 
I want the case to be the markers load and I click them to show info window and then can close the window as well. I've read the docs and issues on Github but can't find the info. Thanks.

```
Index.js

import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";

import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, MarkerClusterer } from "@react-google-maps/api";

import MapMarker from "./MapMarker";

const mapOptions = {
  fullscreenControl: false,
  streetViewControl: false,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  styles: [
    {
      featureType: "poi",
      elementType: "labels",
      stylers: [
        {
          visibility: "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      featureType: "transit",
      elementType: "all",
      stylers: [
        {
          visibility: "off"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
const key = ""; // PUT GMAP API KEY HERE
const defaultLocation = {
  lat: 37.9755691,
  lng: 23.7361789
};
let markers = [
  {
    id: 1,
    lat: 37.975,
    lng: 23.7361789
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    lat: 37.9755,
    lng: 23.7361789
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    lat: 37.976,
    lng: 23.7361789
  }
];

class Map extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isInfoOpen: false,
    selectedMarkerId: null,
    noOfClusters: null,
    markers: markers
  };

  onClick = (isInfoOpen, selectedMarkerId) => {
    this.setState({
      isInfoOpen,
      selectedMarkerId
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { isInfoOpen, selectedMarkerId } = this.state;

    return (
      <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey={key} >
        <div>
          <div
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: 500,
              display: "flex"
            }}
          >
            <GoogleMap
              options={mapOptions}
              center={defaultLocation}
              zoom={18}
              onLoad={this.onMapMounted}
              onIdle={this.onMapIdle}
              onBoundsChanged={this.onBoundsChanged}
              onZoomChanged={this.onZoomChanged}
              mapContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}
            >
              <MarkerClusterer averageCenter enableRetinaIcons gridSize={60}>
                {clusterer =>
                  this.state.markers.map(markerData => (
                    <MapMarker
                      key={markerData.id}
                      clusterer={clusterer}
                      markerData={markerData}
                      isSelected={markerData.id === selectedMarkerId}
                      isInfoOpen={
                        markerData.id === selectedMarkerId && isInfoOpen
                      }
                      onClick={() => this.onClick()}
                    />
                  ))
                }
              </MarkerClusterer>
            </GoogleMap>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </LoadScript>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Map />, rootElement);
```

```
MapMarker.js

import React from "react";

import { InfoWindow, Marker} from "@react-google-maps/api";

export default class MapMarker extends React.Component {
  state = {
    mapMarker: null,
    activeMarker: {},
    selectedPlace: {},
    showingInfoWindow: false
};

onMarkerClick = (props, marker) =>
    this.setState({
        activeMarker: marker,
        selectedPlace: props,
        showingInfoWindow: true
    });

onInfoWindowClose = () =>
    this.setState({
        activeMarker: null,
        showingInfoWindow: false
    });

  onLoad = mapMarker => {
    this.setState({
      mapMarker
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { clusterer, markerData } = this.props;
    const { mapMarker } = this.state;

    return (
      <Marker
        clusterer={clusterer}
        onLoad={this.onLoad}
        position={{ 
          lat: markerData.lat,
          lng: markerData.lng
        }}
        onClick={() => this.onMarkerClick()}

      >
        {mapMarker && (
        <InfoWindow
            anchor={mapMarker}
            position={{
              lat: markerData.lat,
              lng: markerData.lng
            }}  
            marker={this.state.activeMarker}
            onClose={this.onInfoWindowClose}
            visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
          >
            <div style={{ background: "white" }}>
              {"custom Infobox: " + markerData.id}
            </div>
          </InfoWindow>
        )}
      </Marker>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? What have you tried to debug? Can you provide a working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)?

Comment: Hey, no errors. I've been reading the documentation and it makes no reference to being able to open and close info windows by clicking markers. https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#infowindow . I've changed the code a little and here is the sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-faraday-10kbs?file=/src/index.js . I have a cluster, markers and info boxes displaying permanantly and an alert when the marker is clicked but when I close the info box clicking the marker does not re open. Thanks

Comment: Do you *need* multiple info windows to be open at the same time? Otherwise, you should probably use only 1.

Comment: No, ideally just one. Click on a marker and one window displays which I can then close and open another one. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Would that be helpful? https://blog.vanila.io/writing-a-google-maps-react-component-fae411588a91 (look for the section about info windows).

Comment: The first component (`Map`) has `onClick` function which expects to 2 params: `isInfoOpen, selectedMarkerId` but you call it with none: `onClick={() => this.onClick()` so the state doesn't change.

Comment: @MoshFeu OP didn't set an on-click event on the `Map`.

Comment: That library is google-map-react which doesn’t support marker clustering and the one I’m using google-map-react-api which supports clustering but doesn’t seem to support opening into windows. Thanks again for your help. I might have to Compromise something for now until I can make my own.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Search for `onClick = (isInfoOpen, selectedMarkerId) => {` in OP's code..

Comment: To open infoWindow required to parameters, the map and the anchored marker, like infowindow,open(map, marker). It do not has option visible, just open() and close() function. Also no need to put position if already has anchor={marker} or just marker={marker}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a couple of changes in your MapMaker.js from the codesandbox link you provided.

First, I added a state named `showingInfoWindow` and assign a value of `false`. This will be the state that will indicate if the infowindow will be shown or not.

Then, I added a function named `onMarkerClick` which is called everytime the Marker is clicked. This will set the state of `showingInfoWindow` to `true`.

Next, I put a condition in the return of MapMaker class, which will only show the infowindow when the `showingInfoWindow` is set to `true`.

Then, I add the `onInfoWindowClose` function that sets the state of `showingInfoWindow` back to `false`.

Lastly, I added the `onCloseClick` parameter in the  and call the `onInfoWindowClose` function.

You can follow the code snippet below for the changes in MapMaker.js

```
import React from "react";

import { Marker, InfoWindow } from "@react-google-maps/api";


export default class MapMarker extends React.Component {
  state = {
    mapMarker: null,
    showingInfoWindow: false
  };

  onMarkerClick = (props) => {
    this.setState({
      showingInfoWindow: true
    });
  };

  onInfoWindowClose = () =>
    this.setState({
      showingInfoWindow: false
    });

  onLoad = (mapMarker) => {
    this.setState({
      mapMarker
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { clusterer, markerData } = this.props;

    return (
      <Marker
        clusterer={clusterer}
        onLoad={this.onLoad}
        position={{
          lat: markerData.lat,
          lng: markerData.lng
        }}
        clickable
        onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
      >
        {this.state.showingInfoWindow === true && (
          <InfoWindow
            position={{
              lat: markerData.lat,
              lng: markerData.lng
            }}
            onCloseClick={this.onInfoWindowClose}
          >
            <div>
              <p>hello</p>
            </div>
          </InfoWindow>
        )}
      </Marker>
    );
  }
}
```